# Variable declared as variant generates Run-time Error 438 - Object doesn't support this property or method for outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I have the following code for importing emails from Outlook.

Getting an error for line "outlookmail.receivedtime".

> Run-time Error 438 - Object doesn’t support this property or method

```
Sub getDataFromOutlook()
Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
Dim OutlookMail As Variant
Dim i As Integer

Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application

Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

i = 1

For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items

If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range("From_Date").Value Then
    Range("Email_Subejct").Offset(i, 0) = OutlookMail.Subject
    Range("Email_Subejct").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
    Range("Email_Subejct").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    Range("Email_Date").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
    Range("Email_Date").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
    Range("Email_Date").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    Range("Email_Sender").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.SenderName
    Range("Email_Sender").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
    Range("Email_Sender").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    Range("Email_Body").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Body
    Range("Email_Body").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
    Range("Email_Body").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    i = i + 1
End If

Next OutlookMail

Set Folder = Nothing
Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because that particular item is not a `MailItem` or an item that  supports `ReceivedTime`.  Since it looks like you're concerned with the `MailItem` type, try adding a condition to check whether the item is in fact a `MailItem`.

```
For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
    If TypeName(OutlookMail) = "MailItem" Then
        If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range("From_Date").Value Then
            'etc
            '
            '
        End If
    End If
Next OutlookMail
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Domenic mentioned, check if you really have a `MailItem` object, and not `ReportItem` or `MeetingItem`.

To check if it is a `MailItem`, use the `Class` property - it is 43 (`OlObjectClass.olMail`) for the messages. `TypeName` method is more expensive.

```
If OutlookMail.Class = 43 Then
```